# Custom Post Types - trying to make "title" display

Tags: custom-post-types, categories

In WordPress you can easily echo or display the title or the name of a Category like this:

```
<?php echo $category_name ?>
```

However, I've noticed that it does NOT display when I'm in a Custom Post Type. I'm using a popular plugin called "Custom Post Type UI"

Is anyone familiar on how to approach this, i.e. getting the Custom Post Type "category name" to display?

Thanks

Comment: Make sure the category is displayed in the [template file](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#visual-overview) used by your custom post type. How do you determine the name of the category?

Comment: `$category_name` is not a standard WordPress variable. Presumably it is defined by your theme, but maybe not in the template for your CPT. There is too little information in your question to determine what the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about custom post type categories (i.e. terms)?

You can get existing term name by

```
$queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->name;
```